# How doing method map for one React component for once?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, material-ui

I have that code and am just stuck in here:

```
const images = 
  [
    {src: 'someimage', id: 1},
    {src: 'someimage2', id: 2},
    {src: 'someimage3', id: 3}
  ]

  return (
    <ImageList>
      {images.map((item) => (
        <ImageListItem className={classes.media} key={images.id} >
          <img src={item.src} alt={item.title} />
        </ImageListItem>
      ))}
    </ImageList>
);
```

I want to render each ImageListItem component with a separate image, planning to bind it to key.id but I always have results like this:...

[image]

There is upper component:

```
const themes = [1,2,3];
  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container justifyContent="center" spacing={10}>
          {themes.map(() => (
            <Grid item >
              <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
                <Theme/>
              </Paper>
              <Typography align='center' variant="subtitle1">Название</Typography>
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
```

All code from question is in **Theme** component. There are just another method map that rendered all cleanly

Comment: Your `<ImageListItem>` key should be `key={item.id}`

Comment: Thx it's help with react keys but i still have problem with render <ImageListItem>. I want to render one image in one component like if id:1 then image render src:'someimage' etc

Comment: I don't see any other issues with the code you posted.  Can you provide the code for `<ImageList>` and `<ImageListItem>`?  Or, are these components from `MaterialUI`?

Comment: Yes this MaterialUI, how you can see in result i all images renders in one <ImageListItem>  but i need one image in one component, so why all my images render in one <ImageListItem> component? i understand that it is easy but brain just shot down

Comment: Is this all of the code?  There are 2 `<ImageList>` nodes in your dev tools elements view.  Are you defining another one outside of the code block that you posted?  Can you post the full width dev tools window that shows the entire rows?